# I cannot change the nodejs version on vscode under OSX using nvm

Tags: node.js, macos, visual-studio-code, nvm

I see in vscode terminal, my nodejs version is v11.5.0, I need to change the version to 12.13.0, and i do `nvm use 12.13.0`, it successfully executed, then `node -v`, it is still 11.5.0, as the sreenshot below.

At the `/bin/bash` from system, i tried `node -v`, it 12.13.0.

Why cannot i change the version? anyone help! thanks.
you can see the `nvm ls` below in the screenshot.

in vscode terminal

```sh
~$ node -v
v11.5.0
~$ nvm use 12.13.0
Now using node v12.13.0 (npm v6.10.2)
~$ node -v
v11.5.0
~$ nvm ls
       v10.13.0
       v10.15.0
       v10.15.1
       v10.16.0
       v12.13.0
->       system
default -> 12.13.0 (-> v12.13.0)
system -> 12.13.0 (-> v12.13.0)
node -> stable (-> v12.13.0) (default)
stable -> 12.13 (-> v12.13.0) (default)
iojs -> N/A (default)
lts/* -> lts/erbium (-> v12.13.0)
lts/argon -> v4.9.1 (-> N/A)
lts/boron -> v6.17.1 (-> N/A)
lts/carbon -> v8.16.2 (-> N/A)
lts/dubnium -> v10.17.0 (-> N/A)
lts/erbium -> v12.13.0
~$
```

in iTerm

```sh
Last login: Fri Oct 25 10:49:41 on ttys000
~$ node -v
v12.13.0
~$
```

Thanks to @tuan-anh-tran , i try this:

in vscode terminal

```sh
~$ which node
/usr/local/bin/node
```

in system terminal

```sh
~$ which node
/Users/lennon/.nvm/versions/node/v12.13.0/bin/node
~$
```

what's wrong? Both the terminals is `/bin/bash`, why the node is different? is anywhere i should do some settings?

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ffGUb.png)

Comment: are the shell in vscode and in terminal same? can you do `which node` on vscode and on terminal and update the post with it?

Comment: thank you, and i updated the post. any more good news for me? :>, thanks to my nice technology god!

Comment: if seems the $PATH is not loaded in vscode shell but i have no idea what cause it. if it's different shell, I could understand but in your case it's the same shell. if you do `echo $PATH` in both, they are probably different.

Comment: as you said, the `$PATH`s is different, is the system terminal,  `/Users/lennon/.nvm/versions/node/v12.13.0/bin` is before `/usr/local/bin` but after it in the vscode terminal(at the end). why it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @tuan-anh-tran again for nice helping.

By following your tips, I tried `brew info node`, and i found that the nodejs@11.5.0 is installed sometime earlier.

So that i execute `brew uninstall node`, and reopen vscode terminal, the version is 12.13.0, that is correct!

The problem solved, but i still do not known why the `node`s(in vscode terminal and in system terminal) will point to the different program in the same terminal `/bin/bash`, might anywhere need to do some settings.